# Counting in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, count, crosstab

I'm trying to get a df from:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start Time': ['27/02/2018 12:56', '27/02/2018 12:56', '27/02/2018 12:51', '28/02/2018 12:51', '28/02/2018 12:46', '28/02/2018 12:46', '28/02/2018 12:41', '28/02/2018 12:41', '01/03/2018 12:36', '01/03/2018 12:36', '01/03/2018 12:31', '01/03/2018 12:31', '02/03/2018 12:27', '02/03/2018 12:27', '02/03/2018 12:27', '02/03/2018 12:27'], 'Event_type': ['Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer', 'Transfer'], 'Status': ['S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'F', 'S', 'F', 'S', 'F', 'S', 'S', 'F', 'S', 'S', 'F', 'F'], 'Job Number': [1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0, 1000000000000.0]}, columns=['Job Number','Start Time','Event_type','Status'])
```

---

```
print (df)
      Job Number        Start Time Event_type Status
0   1.000000e+12  27/02/2018 12:56   Transfer      S
1   1.000000e+12  27/02/2018 12:56   Transfer      S
2   1.000000e+12  27/02/2018 12:51   Transfer      S
3   1.000000e+12  28/02/2018 12:51   Transfer      S
4   1.000000e+12  28/02/2018 12:46   Transfer      F
5   1.000000e+12  28/02/2018 12:46   Transfer      S
6   1.000000e+12  28/02/2018 12:41   Transfer      F
7   1.000000e+12  28/02/2018 12:41   Transfer      S
8   1.000000e+12  01/03/2018 12:36   Transfer      F
9   1.000000e+12  01/03/2018 12:36   Transfer      S
10  1.000000e+12  01/03/2018 12:31   Transfer      S
11  1.000000e+12  01/03/2018 12:31   Transfer      F
12  1.000000e+12  02/03/2018 12:27   Transfer      S
13  1.000000e+12  02/03/2018 12:27   Transfer      S
14  1.000000e+12  02/03/2018 12:27   Transfer      F
15  1.000000e+12  02/03/2018 12:27   Transfer      F
```

to:

```
Status       F   S  Grand Total
Start Time                     
2018-01-03   2   2            4
2018-02-03   2   2            4
2018-02-27   0   3            3
2018-02-28   2   3            5
Grand Total  6  10           16
```

What I need to do is get a count of the Destination file names with an 'S' tag that occur on a given day, the Status can only be 'S' or 'F'.

The code I'm using so far is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('JobFileAuditLogs20180227_B.csv', encoding='utf-8') 

df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time']).dt.date

df.to_csv('JobFileAuditLogs20180227_C.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
df = pd.read_csv('JobFileAuditLogs20180227_C.csv', index_col='Start Time', 
encoding='utf-8') 

df[['Status', 'Destination File Name']]
```

I tried using

```
df['Status'].value_counts()
```

but this only gives the occurnces of S and F but not how many on each day.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, any help would be great.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please give us data (e.g. `df.head().to_dict()`) to work with, since it's not possible to paste images into python.

Comment: Please consider providing at least a part of that CSV file for testing...

Comment: I think you need `df = pd.crosstab(df['Destination File Name'], df['Status'], margins=True)`

Comment: Is there a way to attach the .csv file here?

Comment: @Ninjasoup - can you copy 10 rows of file to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time']).dt.date,
                 df['Status'], 
                 margins=True,
                 margins_name='Grand Total')
print (df)

Status       F   S  Grand Total
Start Time                     
2018-01-03   2   2            4
2018-02-03   2   2            4
2018-02-27   0   3            3
2018-02-28   2   3            5
Grand Total  6  10           16
```

Comment: This is almost correct, it's counting a bit oddly, the values for `df = pd.crosstab(df['Destination File Name'], df['Status'], margins=True)` gives the correct values but the output look for `df = pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time']).dt.date, df['Status'], margins=True)` is what I'm after

Comment: @Ninjasoup - I am a bit confused, so need my answer solution or solution from comments?

Comment: @Ninjasoup - be free get my sample DataFrame, add new column and create expected output.

Comment: I put some data in the OP

Comment: @Ninjasoup - Can you add expected output from your data?

Comment: One second I just need to check something

Comment: @ jezrael After double checking the data your solution is what I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: @ jezrael Sure, go ahead.